# How to convert a Node Form input to be an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Good Morning coders! I have a backend form that I would like to change from accepting information as a string that is stored in a mongo database to accept an array.

This essentially is a categories input for blog posts that I have limited to a string currently but would like to be able to tag multiple categories (the ultimate goal would be a checkbox dropdown for the field input).

I am using MEAN stack, and have bodyparser installed.

The existing mongo collection where the form updates is:

```
// schema setup
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    postdata: String,
    excerpt: String,
    tag: String,
    icon: String,
    color: String,
    featured: String,
    keywords: String,
    description: String,
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    create: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
   },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Posts", postSchema);
```

First step is obviously to change "TAG" to be to "Array". I am also reading that the form field that is currently:

```
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
  <input type="text" id="tag" class="form-control" name="tag[]" required>
  <label for="tags" class="form-label">Tag</label>
</div>
```

should be changed to something like to have a dropdown that would add selections to the array:

```
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
  <select class="select" multiple>
    <option value="marketing" name="tag[]">marketing</option>
    <option value="seo" name="tag[]">SEO</option>
  </select>
  <label class="form-label select-label">Example label</label>
</div>
```

Currently, I have the usual `var tag = req.body.tag;` that passes into my newPost variable for my Mongo database.

I was curious about 2 questions:

1. Does the bodyparser variable need to change on input now that I am sending an array instead of a string?
2. Does any existing data I have stored previously need to be converted?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do anything to the body-parser. If you were sending the request via the url you would probably need to add:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

but since you are just sending in a normal form you should be fine. It is common practice to have the above code anyway as your app will grow over time and this is a handy option to set.

When you send your form data the `req.body` object will have a property of `tag` and a value of the array you send like so:

```
// req.body
{
    tag: [ 'marketing', 'seo', 'jqueeny' ],
    name: 'bob'
    ...
}
```

The body-parser middleware does all the hard work for you.

Yes, you will  need to convert the existing data as it's a string currently and you need it to be an array.

Since you are now storing tags as an array you will want to ensure they are unique. You can do this with a validation in your schema object like so:

```
tag: {
        type:[String],
        required: [true, 'Each Post must have at least 1 tag.'],
        validate: [(tags) => {
            if(tags.length > 0){ // Need 1 or more tags
               if(tags.every(str => str !== '')){ // Tags can't have empty strings
                  const unqKword = [...new Set(tags)]; // Make new array of unique values
                  return unqKword.length === tags.length; // Tags can't have duplicates
               }
             }
                return false;
            }, 'Each Tag must have a value and must be unique.']
        },
```

This will also allow you to store tags submitted by allowing the user to type  them into the form if you decide to divert away from a drop-down.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I just need to convert the data in the MongoDB and just adjust a few things slightly. This is a back-end form that I am using so I will only be using that dropdown option that I would be pre-populating myself

Comment: Then you probably won't need the validate option if you'll be in control of the tag options. Good luck with project. If you found the answer helpful please mark as accepted.